# Treeview - mysql multiply numbers under 1 tree

Tags: c#, .net, c, treeview

So i got this treeview where i want to display some people with as child some numbers  from my database

so this is my database of clients

/Clientnr/name/surname

and the second database contains their invoice numbers and data

/Invoicnr/Clientnr/status/

now is it possible to make my treeview like

Name Surename 
 |**__ invoic number 

|*_*_** second invoice number 
   |*_*_ another one... until i got them all

i just cant get the invoice numbers under  1 name :)
he makes a parrent for every invoice there is for that person
is it possible to put them all under one instead of making multiply same name's

this is my code now

```
 try
        {


            MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection("SERVER=localhost;" +
                        "DATABASE=factoram;" +
                        "UID=root;" +
                        "PASSWORD=root;");

            new MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT klienten.Klientnr,\n" +
     "klienten.Voornaam,\n" +
     "klienten.Naam,\n" +
     "rekening.Rekeningnr FROM\n" +
     "rekening\n" +
     "INNER JOIN klienten ON rekening.Klientnr = klienten.Klientnr  ORDER BY klienten.naam asc ;", conn).Fill(dt);


            foreach (DataRow r in dt.Rows)
            {
                int b = dt.Rows.IndexOf(r);

                tvfacturen.Nodes.Add(r[1].ToString() + " " + r[2].ToString());

                tvfacturen.Nodes[b].Nodes.Add(r[3].ToString());


            }

        }
        catch (Exception b)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(b.ToString());



        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nodes.Add returns a node. Just call Nodes.add of the property Nodes of the created node.

```
var oNode = this.treeView.Nodes.add("OhYeah");
var oChild = oNode.Nodes.add("child");
```

Sorry I misunderstand, do that instead of your foreach

```
var oGrouped = dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().GroupBy(r => r[1].ToString() + " " + r[2].ToString());
foreach (var oClient in oGrouped)
{
    var oClientNode = this.TreeView.Nodes.Add(oClient.Key);
    foreach (var oInvoice in oClient)
    {
        oClientNode.Nodes.Add(oInvoce[3].ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: im sorry dont realy see what ya mean

Comment: change

            foreach (DataRow r in dt.Rows)
            {
                int b = dt.Rows.IndexOf(r);

                tvfacturen.Nodes.Add(r[1].ToString() + " " + r[2].ToString());

                tvfacturen.Nodes[b].Nodes.Add(r[3].ToString());


            }


by

            foreach (DataRow r in dt.Rows)
            {
           var oNode =      tvfacturen.Nodes.Add(r[1].ToString() + " " + r[2].ToString());

                oNode.Nodes.Add(r[3].ToString());


            }

Comment: the client still show multiply times :) i want all the invoice numbers from that client under the same name :)

Comment: for some reason i get an exp at dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>()

Comment: Error 2 'System.Data.DataRowCollection' does not contain a definition for 'Cast' and the best extension method overload 'System.Data.EnumerableRowCollectionExtensions.Cast<TResult>(System.Data.EnumerableRowCollection)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: You're in .net 2.0 ? If you're in .Net 3.5 (or more) just put using System.Linq; in your using declarations and add a reference to System.Core.dll in your project.